# Method returning itself and a value at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am creating python wrapper on top of mysql connector. So far it was straightforward:

```
class DBconnector:
    def __init__(self, columns=None, values=None):
        #connect to db
        pass

    def getcolumns(self, database=None):
        columns = ("columnA1", "columnA2")
        return columns

    def getvalues(self, table=None, columns=None):
        values = ("valB1", "valB2")
        columns = columns
        return values

    def getprimary_key(self, table=None):
        table_key = "someTableKey"
        return table_key

db_conn = DBconnector()
mycolumns = db_conn.getcolumns()
myvalues = db_conn.getvalues()
mykey = db_conn.getprimary_key()
print(mycolumns, myvalues, mykey)
>>>> ('columnA1', 'columnA2') ('valB1', 'valB2') someTableKey
```

Now, I would like to implement chained methods like `.as_list()`, `.as_dict()` etc... That would give me an ability to get data way I need it in certain cases. For example When I ask `db_conn.getvalues.asdict()` I will get values and columns as a key.
I could implement it like so:

```
class DBconnector:
    def __init__(self, columns=None, values=None):
        #connect to db
        self.columns = columns
        self.values = values

    def getvalues(self, table=None, columns=None):
        self.values = ("valB1", "valB2")
        self.columns = columns
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.values)

    def asdict(self):
        mydict = {}
        for idx, col in enumerate(self.columns):
            mydict[col] = self.values[idx]
        return mydict

db_conn = DBconnector()
mycolumns = db_conn.getvalues(columns=["mycolumn1", "mycolumn2"])
print(mycolumns)
print(type(mycolumns))

mydictcolumns = mycolumns.asdict()
print(mydictcolumns)

>>>> ('valB1', 'valB2')
>>>> <class '__main__.DBconnector'>
>>>> {'mycolumn1': 'valB1', 'mycolumn2': 'valB2'}
```

But I have few problems and a question with this approach:

Main method `getvalues()` would return only object that I can no longer parse directly, I would have to implement additional methods just to get values like `.values()` (?).
Overall I am not sure how not to over complicate, make it user friendly and readable. What would be the proper approach for designing such class/module ?

Comment: **First**: Please use correct upper case letters. **Second**: You are asking more then one question/topic here. Please separate your questions in different stackoverflow questions.

Comment: I have modified for a single question instead. Not sure which upper case letters you are referring to in my mock up code, that comment is too vague. You are faster with down voting rather than helping out.

Comment: Check your subject. Also in your text there are some `i` instead of `I`. Please use `inline code formating` with backticks.

Comment: thanks @buhtz. updated subject to specific question and fixed 3 letters in description. Hope that will help understanding code now. Not sure what is wrong with my inline code formatting but i really hope it is sufficient now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your intent is good ('*friendly and readable*'), the implementation is doubtful:

```
class DBconnector:
    def __init__(self, columns=None, values=None):
        #connect to db
        self.columns = columns
        self.values = values

    def getvalues(self, table=None, columns=None):
        self.values = ("valB1", "valB2")
        self.columns = columns
        return self
```

You initiate a db connector with `columns` and `values`? A connector should allow read and write something to a database, why values? What if one chooses to read something from a database. Where is a table name in your connector? The original code is very confusing, hope you can refactor it to something more readable.

If there was just your question and no code, I'd say make a connector return the native database query result type and keep a separate function outside the class to transform this result to a different type (e.g. tuples to dicts).

Generally, I think a very easy intro to database connectivity is
https://dataset.readthedocs.io/en/latest and also https://ponyorm.com for some quick entry into ORM field.

Comment: thanks for suggestions and reply @EPo ! for initiating columns and values - that was only my idea of how to pass data from one method to another but i guess it was wrong idea :)

Comment: it is okay to exeperiment, but another suggestion is that you can try to stay away from classes as long as you can, just do something with functions - this should help deciding on whether you need a state (class) at all and what the interfaces (fucntion arguments) should be.

Comment: Also you are welcome to mark as accepted if the answer suits

Comment: "for Stack Overflow  make your question more focused next time" - Well this is my issue - i Don't have very specific problem - there is always a way around. I am not sure if my approach is correct, overall way of thinking and this is something i cannot get any help with easy way. It's easy to find straight answers but not easy to understand whenever your approach is good :) and thx for the links, very useful!

Comment: There is also https://codereview.stackexchange.com - you can address more general questions there, but the code must be finished small piece. Here at Stackoverflow the focus is on how to solve a specifc one problem per question. Standard python ORM is SQLAlchemy, but it is a bit hard to use stand-alone, better start with simplier ones like Pony, Peewee, etc.